# How to set a width to turn on browser scroll bars and stop collapsing the elements on the page

Tags: css, scrollbar

I'm creating a banner at the top of my page.  It's built using 3 banners that will have content.  When I horizontally shrink the browser window, my green banner component(on the right) moves with the edge of the screen eventually overlapping or going under my blue banner component (on the left).

How do I set a browser(body?) width at which the banner on the right stops moving with the shrinking browser and instead enable the browser scroll bars so the page stops shrinking?

If there's an entirely different/better way to approach this please throw all suggestions at me.  Trying to learn as much as possible.

Your help is much appreciated.  My code is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <style media="screen" type="text/css">

    .bannerBackground
        {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 27px;
        background-color: orange;
        }

    .rightBanner
        {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        z-index: 9;
        height: 27px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: right;
        color: #CCCCCC;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: green;
        margin:0;
        display: block;
        }

    .leftBanner
        {
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 10;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        width: 645px;
        background-color: blue;
        height: 27px;
        display: block;
        }

    body
        {
        font-family: arial;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #EEEEEE;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>

        <div class="leftBanner">
        </div>

        <div class="rightBanner">
            <div>
            Some Title Text
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bannerBackground">
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the link to the page, if its online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you absolutely position elements you take them out of the flow of the page. You can instead use floats.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style media="screen" type="text/css">

.bannerBackground
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: 27px;
    background-color: orange;
    }

.rightBanner
    {
    z-index: 9;
    height: 27px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: green;
    margin:0;
float: right;
    }

.leftBanner
    {
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 10;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 645px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 27px;
float: left;
    }

body
    {
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #EEEEEE;
min-width: 960px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="leftBanner">
    </div>

    <div class="rightBanner">
        <div>
        Some Title Text
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bannerBackground">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  That's exactly what I wanted.  For educational purposes, is there a way to do it while leaving the position: absolute in there?

Comment: I'm asking because I'd also like to create the same sort of thing at the bottom of my page and then set a min-height.  I assume I'd need to use position: absolute to do that, of course being very green, I don't put a lot of stock in my assumptions.

Comment: if thats the case you would want to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sD3d9/1/

Position the containing elements but not the elements within.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the position:absolute . Then you could put it all in a container div and float the banners left and right with the body in the middle . That's how I'd do it.