# inline-divs wrapping

Tags: css, html

I have two side-by-side inline-divs with widths of 400px.

When the browser is resized to less than 800px width, the second div wraps and overlaps the first. I want them to stay side-by-side with a horizontal scroll bar added to the browser window. I have tried styling body and the divs with whitespace: nowrap. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS. You could put "min-width: 800px;" css property on the container of those divs

Comment: Same as this one if you want an example.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142071/how-to-set-a-width-to-turn-on-browser-scroll-bars-and-stop-collapsing-the-elemen/8142210#8142210

Comment: All the suggestions are good so far. I hate to do extra coding and add overhead. As we continue to code more to make simple things work, the loading time increases. Just position absolute solves the entire puzzle. See my answer and demo below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. It should be white-space: nowrap. Thanks for the suggestions though...

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping them in a div with a width of 800px.

Answer (score 0):

You would also probably have to set a style of min-width to the parent div

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style='position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:400px; 
 height:250px; background-color:yellow; ' >
</div>

<div style='position:absolute; top:0; left:401px; width:400px; 
 height:320px; background-color:red; '>
</div>
```

http://zequinha-bsb.int-domains.com/side-by-side.html

```
EDIT: Bare in mind that absolute positioning requires parent to have 
position:relative explicit
```

Answer (score 0):

since your widths are fixed just create an outer div container

```
<div class="bigbox">
   <div class="leftbox">
   </div>
   <div class="rightbox">
   </div>
</div>

.bigbox { width: 810px;}
.leftbox { width: 400px; float: left}
.rightbox {width: 400px; float: right}
```